# what does "lid device is not compliant to SW_LID." mean?

Tags: debian

what does this mean and how do I correct it?

```
# cat /var/log/messages | grep -a 'lid'
Mar 22 00:36:00 debian kernel: [ 1039.517767] ACPI: button: The lid device is not compliant to SW_LID.
```

System:

```
# uname -a
Linux debian 4.19.0-8-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.98-1 (2020-01-26) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This message comes from `drivers/acpi/button.c` which is a part of
`ACPI_BUTTON` module in the Linux kernel.
For example, under `linux-source-4.19/drivers/acpi/button.c` after line `171` you can find it:

```
194 /* Complain the buggy firmware */
195 pr_warn_once("The lid device is not compliant to SW_LID.\n");
```

As you can see this message is printed when *the buggy firmware* is
detected.  The comment carries on:

```
196 /*
197  * Send the unreliable complement switch event:
.    *
.    * On most platforms, the lid device is reliable. However
.    * there are exceptions:
.    * 1. Platforms returning initial lid state as "close" by
.    *    default after booting/resuming:
.    *     https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=89211
.    *     https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=106151
.    * 2. Platforms never reporting "open" events:
.    *     https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=106941
.    * On these buggy platforms, the usage model of the ACPI
.    * lid device actually is:
.    * 1. The initial returning value of _LID may not be
.    *    reliable.
.    * 2. The open event may not be reliable.
.    * 3. The close event is reliable.
.    *
.    * But SW_LID is typed as input switch event, the input
.    * layer checks if the event is redundant. Hence if the
.    * state is not switched, the userspace cannot see this
.    * platform triggered reliable event. By inserting a
.    * complement switch event, it then is guaranteed that the
.    * platform triggered reliable one can always be seen by
.    * the userspace.
222  */
```

How to fix it - it's just a diagnostic message, if everything works
fine for you, you can ignore it.  In case something doesn't work you should
visit the links posted above and search for possible solutions for the
particular hardware you have or try to upgrade your computer's firmware
which unluckily may not be always possible from Linux.

Comment: thanks for the hints! I have some questions still. should I have a file `drivers/acpi/button.c` in my machine? `find` can't show it..

Comment: I don't use Debian but you might have Linux source code in
`/usr/src/linux-$(uname -r)` and if you don't you may have to install
linux-source package.

Comment: hhmm.... do I need the acpi-package?

Comment: Why? Does it contain Linux source code? https://www.google.com/search?q=debian+linux+source+package

Comment: I didn't have `usr/src/linux...`, so I have installed `linux-source`. now I have `linux-config-4.19/`, `linux-patch-4.19-rt.patch.xz`, and `linux-source-4.19.tar.xz`. how does this lead me to `/acpi/button.c`?

Comment: `tar tf /usr/src/linux-source-4.19.tar.xz | grep acpi/button.c` -> `linux-source-4.19/drivers/acpi/button.c`. It's just an example, I have run it in Debian Docker container, modify 4.19 accordingly or use `$(uname -r)`

Comment: now it's clear. thanx! out of curiosity, which distribution do you use?

Comment: I use Slackware.